# ATTiny85 VirtualWire AnalogRead 1

Tags: attiny, virtualwire

My **ATTiny85** is connected to a **433 transmitter** and an **analog sound sensor**. The 433 is working fine (using **VirtualWire**) but when I send the reading from the sensor all I receive is a 1.

What I would like to receive is the value between 0 and 1024 like when I print the sensor to serial. I cannot check it because the ATTiny85 had no serial out.

My code is a combination of snippets I found online, I am not happy with all the magic to format the data that needs sending. I would also like to send "Reading: 637" in stead of just the number but I find the concatenation Google results extremely complicated.

Should this code send the sensor data like 672?
Could there maybe be some Fuse setting blocking the AnalogRead?

```
#include <VirtualWire.h>

const int transmit_pin = PB0;
const int sensor_pin = PB4;
int sensor_data;
char sensor_msg[4];

void setup()
{
  vw_set_tx_pin(transmit_pin);
  vw_setup(2000);
}

int count = 1;

void loop()
{

  sensor_data = analogRead(sensor_pin);
  itoa(sensor_data,sensor_msg,4);
  vw_send((uint8_t *)sensor_msg, strlen(sensor_msg));
  vw_wait_tx(); // Wait until the whole message is gone
  _delay_ms(1000);
  count = count + 1;

}
```

**Receiver Code as requested**
This is a Pro Mini (clone) and it has an LCD attached so I can see what is going on.

```
#include <VirtualWire.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>

LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x27,16,2);

const int receive_pin = 11;
char* testje;
void setup()
{
    delay(1000);
    Serial.begin(9600); // Debugging only
    Serial.println("setup");

    // Initialise the IO and ISR
    vw_set_rx_pin(receive_pin);
    vw_setup(2000);  // Bits per sec

    vw_rx_start();       // Start the receiver PLL running

    lcd.init();
    lcd.backlight();
    lcd.home();
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.print("hello");
    delay(1000);
    lcd.clear();
}

void loop()
{
  char buf[VW_MAX_MESSAGE_LEN];
  uint8_t buflen = VW_MAX_MESSAGE_LEN;

  if (vw_get_message(buf, &buflen)) {
    int i;
    // Message with a good checksum received, print it.
    Serial.print("Got: ");

    for (i = 0; i < buflen; i++) {
       Serial.print((char)buf[i]);
    }
    Serial.println();
    Serial.println(buf);
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.print(buf);
  }
}
```

Comment: sensor_msg should be 5 bytes long not 4, but other than that it looks fine. What is your reception code? Maybe the bug lies there?

Comment: Actually, one thing i just noticed. The third argument of itoa should be 10 not 4. That argument is the base you want to represent the value in.

Comment: thanks, I've changed it. also tried HEX but 1 stays 1 obviously :D I will find an extra Pro Mini to test the sending of the data from a Pro Mini, will update my question afterwards

Comment: I would double check the pin numbers for the attiny. They look like port bit numbers but that might just work by chance.

Comment: Ok from a Pro Mini it all works. So the code is ok and the receiver is ok. About the pins; I use PB0 to send data, so PB4 must be PB4 right? It's not possible to name it A2 but it 'should be' that pin. I will make a blinking LED on PB3 to be sure :) maybe I can have it blink analogeRead/100 or something..

Comment: Tusen tack! It was the pin number after all... `PB0` for physical pin 5 and `2` for physical pin 3. Awesome! Please convert something to an answer so I can give you credits :) Now I have to stop my LED routine because it is trying to blink the value 1023 :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would double check the pin numbers for the attiny. They look like port bit numbers but that might just work by chance.

```
const int transmit_pin = PB0;
const int sensor_pin = PB4;
```

A quick double check with the [attiny/pins_arduino.h](https://github.com/damellis/attiny/blob/master/variants/tiny8/pins_arduino.h#L33) give:

```
// ATMEL ATTINY45 / ARDUINO
//
//                 +-\/-+
// Ain0 (D5) PB5  1|    |8  Vcc
// Ain3 (D3) PB3  2|    |7  PB2 (D2) Ain1
// Ain2 (D4) PB4  3|    |6  PB1 (D1) pwm1
//           GND  4|    |5  PB0 (D0) pwm0
//                 +----+
```

As you have found they should be defined as:

```
const int transmit_pin = 0; // Physical pin 5
const int sensor_pin = 4;   // and pin 3
```

This type of issue could be avoided by using strong data typing and object oriented design. Please see for instance Cosa [ATtinyX5.hh](https://github.com/mikaelpatel/Cosa/blob/master/cores/cosa/Cosa/Board/Arduino/ATtinyX5.hh) and [GPIO.hh](https://github.com/mikaelpatel/Cosa/blob/master/cores/cosa/Cosa/GPIO.hh).

Cheers!

[Here](https://github.com/mikaelpatel/Cosa-Domotica/blob/master/RF433/DomoticaAnalogPin/DomoticaAnalogPin.ino) is something that does basically the same as the sender. Cosa supports attiny and Arduino boards "out-of-the-box".